# How to create dummy variables for use in a GLM in R?

Tags: r, glm

I'm trying to run a binominal GLM (in R but open to testing other software), my DV is a y/n, my IDV's include such things as gender, age by group (neonate, subadult, ect), length, weight an a couple others.

I want to know whether I need dummy variables and if so, how I convert factors with more than 2 possible outcomes into dummy variables.

Comment: R should take care of making dummy variables for factor variables so just make sure your variables are formatted as factors. It would be easier to be more specific with a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about **design matrix**, a matrix with rows for your observations and columns with the coefficients (that includes your coefficient and dummy variables).

R will automatically create a design matrix for you internally with **model.matrix**, so you don't have to do anything. Just make sure you specify the correct variables. Your categorical variables should be stored as a factor.

If you want to be convinced, type `glm` in R for the source code. You will see this:

```
X <- if (!is.empty.model(mt)) 
    model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
```

Yes. You can create your own design matrix and give it to the `glm` function. ?glm gives you:

```
glm.fit(x, y ...
```

Follow the documentation.

Comment: But note that categorical variables should either be stored as or converted to factor before doing this